# Xcode 5 Command Line: invalid deployment target '3.0.0' for architecture 'arm64'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I'm building a fat Crypto++ library from the command line under Xcode 5 with the iOS 7 SDK. The iOS 7 SDK includes the `arm64` target. All goes well for the `armv7` and `armv7s` architectures, but `arm64` is a different matter:

```
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g -Os -pipe -fPIC -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM -arch arm64
--sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
-Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-value -c 3way.cpp
error: invalid deployment target '3.0.0' for architecture 'arm64' (requires '7.0.0' or later)
1 error generated.
make: *** [3way.o] Error 1
```

I've never experienced the error before, and searching produced no hits. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the command line option:

```
-mios-version-min=7.0.0
```

or:

```
-miphoneos-version-min=7.0.0
```

See this [clang reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the armv64 from vaild - architure in build setting and run the project

[image]

Comment: Thanks Deepesh. I'm building purely from the command line, and I want the ARM64 architecture in the fat library.

Answer (score 0):

Try /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++

Comment: Thanks user2848657. My cross-compile scripts sets the toolchain to Xcode's default. trojanfoe provided the answer to this problem for me.