# Linker error when trying to integrate GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS library into Xcode Old project

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, arm64

I have created a completely new project using Xcode 5 and successfully integrated `Google AdMob SDK`.

But when I tried to integrate it with a project(that I imported from Xcode 4.5) it give me Linker errors

```
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Directory not found for option .......
```

A few observations while build with the following targets

```
iPhone Simulator(4-inch 64-bit)  ->  Successful !!
iPhone Simulator(Other 32 bit)   ->  Failed
iPhone 5                         ->  Failed
iPod 4th Gen                     ->  Failed
```

Based on this I think there is some problem in app Build Settings, can you please pin point the issue and a solution

Comment: see my so Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087887/xcode-5-command-line-invalid-deployment-target-3-0-0-for-architecture-arm64/19088013#19088013  and solve your problem

Comment: @Deepesh : Thanks for the tip, though I had tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: please send trhe  Google AdMob SDK link

Comment: @Deepesh : http://dl.google.com/dl/googleadmobadssdk/googleadmobadssdkios.zip

Comment: read the doc https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios I think you forget the -Objc in Other Linker Flags

Comment: @Deepesh :  Tried that too, though it didn't work. :-( Posted an answer of my own, it is hack rather than a solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40930/discussion-between-deepesh-and-rahulg)

Answer (score 0):

Build Settings ->Other Linker Flags -> add this flag -Objc

```
Click on your project (targets)
Click on Build Settings
Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths
```

Comment: Tried that too, but didn't work. I have posted a hack to bypass the error though.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, though not a perfect world solution, but can survive with it.

I removed all valid architectures other than `armv7`.

i.e. Project -> Build Settings -> Architectures -> Delete `armv7s` `arm64`

Waiting for a better answer, though!